# problem in install service pack 1 for windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I need service pack 1 for windows 7 . Because it is need for Android Studio . I downloaded service pack 1 . In progress of install , i receive message :
installation was not successful . The windows 7 service pack installation can not proceed until your computer is restart . Please restart your computer and try again .

I restart my computer , but i receive this message again .
What can i do to install service pack 1 for windows 7 correctly ?

I try 4 times . and i see that problem again .